# unique user identification for a website

Tags: javascript, java, php, python

I'm developing a website to find out the best politician of my state.In my website visitors can vote for their favorite politician.
I want to restrict the users adding more than one vote to a politician and also wants to restrict a user vote for more than one politician (A user can give one vote to any one politician).

How can I trace unique users? I'm not interested in adding a registration/logon method which will reduce the user interaction. I tried to trace unique IP address, but website can be accessed through proxy servers and that method will not work.

Is there any way to trace users?

Comment: Not in a reliable way.

Comment: Learn more here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage
This site uses it to increase counter - http://www.utswmedicine.org/coc This site also - http://www.itcanwait.com/all.

Answer (score 0):

For this task, you have to user registration/login functionality. Otherwise, you will get incorrect data.

My suggested workflow:

1. User registers on site with his email id.
2. Confirmation mail goes to user.
3. User clicks on confirm link and proves that he is genuine.
4. After that he votes.
5. His vote gets recorded against his email id.

Comment: Actually it is a simple method. But the users will not interested in tasks like registration,conformation or even log on. Currently i added a social media login(facebook auth,twitter auth and google login) in my site. But i want to change it to get more user interaction.

Comment: This is a better option, but not a reliable one either, since a user can register under multiple accounts. I think the only answer is expressed by the first comment (@Kayman's). BTW, the OP explicitly says registration is unacceptable